# OOP in Kotlin (lateinit)

Tags: android, kotlin, oop

I'm doing a Kotlin tutorial for android app development and in order to use View Bindig it says to replace the MainActivity class with this code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
    }
}
```

What is the advantage of initializing the `binding` object inside the `onCreate` function?
What would be the difference, if I just initilized it outside of the function, like this:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(binding.root)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably get a `NullPointerException` doing it like that .
reason being [LayoutInflater](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater) is a System Service which needs a valid context to get initialized with  `Context#getSystemService` .

So if you try to access context Globally inside Activity it will probably be null because Activity's lifecycle hasn't been started  yet . `onCreate` is the starting point for Activity . That is the reason behind using `lateinit` and initializing it inside `onCreate` . You can only use your activity as a Context with in `onCreate()` or later in the activity lifecycle till `onDestroy`.

This goes for all other context bind things like `resources` , `packageManager` etc ..

Answer (score 0):

when you are working on an activity the activity is initialized in the on create method. According to google [the activity life cycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle), you should do all the bindings in the onCreate method. Why, before the onCreate method is called the activity variables like context are null because they are not initialized yet. they are all initialized in onCreate method when `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` is called, after the execution of this statement context is initialized and you can use it to initialize the binding. before that the context will be null and you will get a null pointer exception if you accessed context before onCreate.Hope this answers your question.
**I suggest you read the activity life cycle [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)to have better understanding**